# Move an Image bitmap on a Path drawn on layout background

Tags: android, animation, background, path, imageview

I need to move a bitmap image on a path drawn in background of my layout, it can be also a movement of the bitmap inside another bitmap. The movement is caused by smartphone's accelerometer. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortest answer ever - 'Use OpenGL, Luke'
You can also use one of OGL frameworks i.e. AndEngine.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I have downloaded the AndEngine's jar and now I'm study how it works here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4UGcI31oKPY